# NetInfo reports connected during startup and same actions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, middleware

I'm using redux and NetInfo to manager connection detection during startup and any actions where connection is important.

```
import createOneShotMiddleware from 'redux-middleware-oneshot';
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';
import { checkConnection } from '../actions/networkActions';

export const middleware = createOneShotMiddleware((dispatch) => {
    const handle = (isConnected) => dispatch(checkConnection(isConnected));
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(handle);
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', handle);
});
```

Actions

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';

export function checkConnection(isConnected) {
  return {
    type: types.CHECK_CONNECTION,
    isConnected: isConnected
  };
}
```

Reducers

```
import { CHECK_CONNECTION } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  isConnected: false,
};


export default function network(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHECK_CONNECTION:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isConnected: action.isConnected})
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { middleware as netInfo } from './Middleware/redux-middleware-react-native-netinfo';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'

import * as reducers from './reducers';

import NavigationScreen from './Containers/NavigationScreen';

const logger = createLogger()
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger, netInfo)(createStore)
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer)

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationScreen />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

It's not work and don't update the state, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is old but for anyone that arrives here in the future this is how i have done it i tend to do this on my actions creators:

```
export function networkCheck(){
  return (dispatch) => {
    const dispatchNetworkState = (isConnected) => dispatch({
      type: types.NETWORK_STATE,
      state: isConnected
    })
    const handle = () => NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(dispatchNetworkState)
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', handle);
  }
}
```

the isue on the code before is that is not following the chain of eventlistener -> testNetwork -> dispatch result